# Short story with a carnivorous moving dot on his wall that eats his dog

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

It's a short story that I read when I was younger and I can't find it anywhere now. I believe the last line was along the lines of: "Watch out boy, that thing's carnivorous." I believe it took place in the 1800s-1900s.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  There isn't very much detail here; you should take a look at the [suggestions for a good story-id question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if you remember any additional information you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: I once read something similar. The idea seemed to be that every time the spot reappeared, it was larger. Toward the end -- the version I saw had illustrations to show us -- the thing was getting much, much larger than the cute little "inkblot" it had once seemed to be, and its shape was developing so that it appeared to have teeth and so forth. Does that sound like your story?

Comment: @Lorendiac - I think that was Gahan Wilson's story in _Again, Dangerous Visions_. Different from this one, I think. Title is a graphical "blot" (http://www.baen.com/Chapters/ERBAEN0059/ERBAEN005902.jpg).

Comment: Yes! That's it thank you so much!

Comment: probably the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/260951/short-story-concerning-a-dangerous-ink-blot (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 10):

I think that was Gahan Wilson's story in [*Again, Dangerous Visions*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?224813). Title is a graphical "blot" [image: https://baen.com/Chapters/ERBAEN0059/ERBAEN005902.jpg], and Wilson does indeed refer to the story as "Blot".  (It is listed as "[*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?42234)" on ISFDB and "[[A spot]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Again,_Dangerous_Visions)" on Wikipedia.)

You have slightly misremembered the last line. It is:

> "That's right, Archer," he said, the door swinging open, all unnoticed, behind his back. "The thing's a carnivore."